# getResponseDataAsString jmeter of controller

Tags: if-statement, controller, jmeter

Is possible to check the `getResponseDataAsString` result of an `httprequest` an an if controller in `jmeter`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible given you use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) and invoke [ctx.getPreviousResult() method](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getPreviousResult--) there. `ctx` stands for JMeterContext class instance and represents current thread (virtual user) context.

Example condition which checks if the immediately previous Sampler response data contains `foo` character sequence:

```
${__groovy(ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString().contains('foo'),)}
```

[image]

So if `Some Sampler` response data contains `foo` - `Some Other Sampler` will be executed and vice versa.

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/)